# Is it normal to have big difference between train loss and test loss on neural networks when using class weights

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, unbalanced-classes, keras

I am training a simple feed forward neural network in Keras, to perform binary classification. Dataset is unbalanced, with 10% of class 0 and 90% of class 1, so I was adding a  *class_weight* parameter to create a better model.

I divided dataset into train, eval and test subsets, to have honest results and added a callback that calculates auc on eval subset, a callback for early stopping and callback for saving best model.

However I cannot see overfitting, because val auc and test auc are similar, the test loss and val loss are not.

[image: Training with class weight]

When training without *class_weight* set results are slightly worse, but the train loss and test loss are similar.

[image]

I know when the classes are balanced, baseline loss is about 0.69, and for my case when not using class weights it would be 0.33, based on: [What's considered a good log loss?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276067/whats-considered-a-good-log-loss)

I am posting my code below.

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y)
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.2, random_state=0, stratify=y_train)

# X_train : 10000, X_val: 2500, X_test: 3000
class_weight = {0: np.mean(y),
                1: 1 - np.mean(y)}
# {0: 0.89728767, 1: 0.10271233320236206}

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.5, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],)))
model.add(Dense(96, input_dim=X_train.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(96, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy])

history = model.fit(X_train,
                    y_train,
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                    epochs=120,
                    batch_size=120,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=callbacks,
                     class_weight=class_weight
                    )

print(f'Val auc: {roc_auc_score(y_val, model.predict_proba(X_val))}')
print(f'Test auc: {roc_auc_score(y_test, model.predict_proba(X_test))}')
# Val auc: 0.7056949806949808
# Test auc: 0.7185675253451476

plt.plot(history.history['acc'], label='train acc')
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'], label='test acc')
plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='train loss')
plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='test loss')
plt.plot(aucCallback.val_aucs, label='auc')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Is it normal when applying class weight to observe such difference?