# Can you estimate average precision from log loss?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, binary-data, loss-functions, average-precision

I am doing my final thesis in the field of **Deepfakes** and their detection. The final outcome is to have a binary classifier which could predict which video was updated and which was not. In other words, if video is fake, output number close to 1 and if video is real, output number close to 0. One of the reasons I started this project is because Facebook released a massive dataset called **DFDC** and they announced in media that the best solution got only 82% average precision on validation dataset and 65% average precision on the testing dataset. Source: https://ai.facebook.com/datasets/dfdc/

However, they also released a research paper describing the results: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.07397.pdf
This is the part where I am confused. Research paper does not mention anything about 82% and 65%. Contradictory, in their research paper's figure you can see that Average Precision of the best score was around 0.98 (on the public testing dataset)

[image]

However, they also include the log loss scores and I managed to understand how Facebook calculates the values of 82% and 65% on public dataset and private dataset. What they do is described in the answer here: [What's considered a good log loss?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276067/whats-considered-a-good-log-loss)
which basically if the log-loss is 0.42, they take average precision as:

$$
ap = \frac{1}{{e^{0.42}}} = 0.657
$$

I was wondering if it is acceptable to use the above method because when I evaluate my score with scikit library and use: average_precision_score, I get much higher scores if to compare with the method which Facebook used as in [What's considered a good log loss?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/276067/whats-considered-a-good-log-loss)